# Renaming only a particular string in a filename recursively

Tags: linux, hdfs

I have a directory with 90 files. The file name is like 
`/user/jk/2016d/IDPSRU20160219_2345.txt`

I want to change the filename to `/user/jkris03/2016d/IDPSRU20160223_2345.txt`

Please note that only `19` is replaced with `23` in the filename and the subsequent `_2345` will be different for each file.

I would appreciate very much if you could provide the answer.

Please note that, the direcory/files are in hdfs.

Thanks,

Comment: Please note that the directory or files are in hdfs

Comment: I suggest you go through this [Stackoverflow Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: From your description, it looks like you want to change `jk` with `jkris03` and  `19` with `23` for all the files. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, you are right. But,  I don/t have to bother about jk or jkris. I can leave it as it is. The only thing , i want to change is 19 to 23.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to replace `19_` with `23_`, you can do something like this:

```
hdfs dfs -ls -C /user/jk/2016d/ | awk '{OLD=$0; sub("19_", "23_", $0); system("hdfs dfs -mv "OLD" "$0);}'
```

where,

`hdfs dfs -ls -C /user/jk/2016d/` : is for listing the HDFS files

`OLD=$0` : is for storing the old file name

`sub("19_", "23_", $0)` : is for creating new file name

`system("hdfs dfs -mv "OLD" "$0)` : is for renaming the file

Hope it helps!

Comment: **Note:** `-C` is available in hadooop versions starting from 2.8.0

Comment: Right! If you are using <2.8.0 you have to change the command to something like this: `hdfs dfs -ls /user/jk/2016d/ | grep -v "Found" | awk '{OLD=$8; sub("19_", "23_", $8); system("hdfs dfs -mv "OLD" "$8);}'
`

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the `rename` command. It allows you to rename by regex. I think it differs between different distributions, so use `man rename` to see how it works for you.